# display just the label from node_lode()

Tags: entities

How to display just the label from the object returned by the function
node_load().
the field_view_field() can hide the label and view the value
but i want the converse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find the label for a specific field then you can use field_info_instance()

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7

```
<?php
$field_instance = field_info_instance('node', 'field_body', 'article');
$label = $field_instance['label'];
?>
```

However, the titles are available in the rendered node if they are not hidden in your view mode, and can accessed like :

```
<?php
$node  = node_view(node_load($nid));
$label = $node['field_body']['#title'];
?>
```

Comment: i found this pretty short: 
<?=render($content['field_address']['#title'])?>
inside the node.tpl.php thanks for your support